# How to add rollingfileappender and dailyrollingfileappender in a single log4j properties

Tags: java

I was implementing log file based on the time and date using Log4j tool for my java application I am facing problem   when i am including both file appender (RollingFileAppender and DaillyRollingFileAppender) in the same properties file. This is the properties configuration i was trying .any clue would be appreciated .

```
log=logs log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File = log/log.txt log4j.appender.FILE.Append = true
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize = 1kb
log4j.appender.FILE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern = [%p] %d %c %M -%m%n%n
```

Comment: Can you tell us what problem are you facing or we have guess it?

Comment: Where is `DaillyRollingFileAppender` in your configuration?

Comment: Dear Braj, The problem is that i am not able to include both functionality in a single property file. I am only able to use any one feature of it ie Either DaillyRollingFileAppender Or RollingFileAppender thanks

Comment: Look at my post first. How are you using it. how can you say that I can use only one feature?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
```

instead of

```
log=logs log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
```

---

one property per line

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File = log/log.txt 
log4j.appender.FILE.Append = true
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize = 1kb
log4j.appender.FILE.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern = [%p] %d %c %M -%m%n%n
```